# How can I check Instance State when I first launch it?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk

When I first launch instance in AWS by java SDK. How can I check the instance state. The state of the created instance is pending and will become running. I want to check the state and wait for the time as soon as possible rather than waiting a fix time like `sleep(100000)`. I try a lot of ways to deal, but the state can't change in SDK.

My final way is:

```
            String pendingId = null;
        while(!createdInstanceId.equals(pendingId)) {
            describeInstancesRequest = ec2.describeInstances();
            reservations = describeInstancesRequest.getReservations();
            Reservation reservation = describeInstancesRequest.getReservations().get(0);
            pendingId = reservation.getInstances().get(0).getInstanceId();
            System.out.println("id: " + pendingId);
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(20000);
        }
```

The id of created instance can receive immediately when I launch the instance. So, I want to query the id of first instance in the instance list until the id is equal to the created instance's id. However, this doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting state of EC2 instance Java API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828964/getting-state-of-ec2-instance-java-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `DescribeInstancesRequest` and then store the result of it inside of a `DescribeInstancesResult` variable in order to read the data.  A method I created some time ago that did just that is:

```
public Integer getInstanceStatus(String instanceId) {
    DescribeInstancesRequest describeInstanceRequest = new DescribeInstancesRequest().withInstanceIds(instanceId);
    DescribeInstancesResult describeInstanceResult = ec2.describeInstances(describeInstanceRequest);
    InstanceState state = describeInstanceResult.getReservations().get(0).getInstances().get(0).getState();
    return state.getCode();
}
```

The code that is returned will be an `Integer` that matches one of the following:

```
0 : pending
16 : running
32 : shutting-down
48 : terminated
64 : stopping
80 : stopped
```

So you'd simply put a call to the `.getInstaceStatus(instanceID)` command inside of a while loop with a reasonable sleep to refresh the status check until the instance is in the desired state.

```
Integer instanceState = -1;
while(instanceState != 16) { //Loop until the instance is in the "running" state.
    instanceState = getInstanceStatus(myInstanceID);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

Just remember to put the loop in its own thread if you need to perform other tasks while waiting for the instance to reach its desired state.

Comment: Thx, i will try it later. I still have a question. What's the relation between reservation and instance? by comparing your answer, i find my wrong answer maybe is from i didnt new request each time.

Comment: Yep, you need to refresh your check, or else you're just reading old data.  The `ec2.describeInstances(describeInstanceRequest)` is the part that actually contacts Amazon for the info.  Also, there is another thread that attempts to answer the question about reservations, and appears to do a decent job of it.  The official documentation on it is a bit lacking as far as describing what it is, exactly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618825/what-is-the-purpose-of-reservations-in-amazon-ec2